# Pandas DataFrame - OutOfBoundsDatetime after date filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In jupyter notebook I often run in a OutOfBoundsDatetime exception when plotting a DataFrame and I really can't get understand why.

1. The exception is only raised on plot, the dataframe seems otherwise fine and usable.
2. For the following example, adding a timedelta to min_date seems to trigger the issue.
3. I've encountered it many times in similar cases but there seem to be a range of things that can trigger it.

### Minimal code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":['2022-06-21T13:53:27.7800', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.7900', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8000',
                           '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8100', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8200', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8300',
                           '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8400', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8500', '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8600',
                           '2022-06-21T13:53:27.8700'], 
                   "values":[40.95, 40.41, 40.346, 40.283, 40.22, 40.28, 40.34, 40.375, 40.41, 40.375]})
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
min_date = (datetime.strptime('2022-06-21T13:53:27.7900', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f') - timedelta(milliseconds=10))
max_date = (datetime.strptime('2022-06-21T13:53:27.8500', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f') + timedelta(milliseconds=10))
df = df[(df.index >= min_date) & (df.index <= max_date)]
display(df)
df.plot()
```

### my conf:

- Python 3.8.13
- notebook==6.4.12
- numpy==1.18.1
- plotly==4.6.0
- pandas==1.0.1

### full error:

```
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfBoundsDatetime                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [113], in <cell line: 21>()
     19 df = df[(df.index >= min_date) & (df.index <= max_date)]
     20 display(df)
---> 21 df.plot()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py:847, in PlotAccessor.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    844             label_name = label_kw or data.columns
    845             data.columns = label_name
--> 847 return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py:61, in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     59         kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     60 plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 61 plot_obj.generate()
     62 plot_obj.draw()
     63 return plot_obj.result

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:269, in MPLPlot.generate(self)
    266 self._adorn_subplots()
    268 for ax in self.axes:
--> 269     self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
    270     self._post_plot_logic(ax, self.data)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:437, in MPLPlot._post_plot_logic_common(self, ax, data)
    434 """Common post process for each axes"""
    436 if self.orientation == "vertical" or self.orientation is None:
--> 437     self._apply_axis_properties(ax.xaxis, rot=self.rot, fontsize=self.fontsize)
    438     self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
    440     if hasattr(ax, "right_ax"):

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:520, in MPLPlot._apply_axis_properties(self, axis, rot, fontsize)
    512 """ Tick creation within matplotlib is reasonably expensive and is
    513     internally deferred until accessed as Ticks are created/destroyed
    514     multiple times per draw. It's therefore beneficial for us to avoid
    515     accessing unless we will act on the Tick.
    516 """
    518 if rot is not None or fontsize is not None:
    519     # rot=0 is a valid setting, hence the explicit None check
--> 520     labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
    521     for label in labels:
    522         if rot is not None:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1201, in Axis.get_majorticklabels(self)
   1199 def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1200     """Return this Axis' major tick labels, as a list of `~.text.Text`."""
-> 1201     ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1202     labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()]
   1203     labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()]

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1371, in Axis.get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1369 r"""Return the list of major `.Tick`\s."""
   1370 if numticks is None:
-> 1371     numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
   1373 while len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:
   1374     # Update the new tick label properties from the old.
   1375     tick = self._get_tick(major=True)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1277, in Axis.get_majorticklocs(self)
   1275 def get_majorticklocs(self):
   1276     """Return this Axis' major tick locations in data coordinates."""
-> 1277     return self.major.locator()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py:1343, in AutoDateLocator.__call__(self)
   1341 dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1342 locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
-> 1343 return locator()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py:434, in MilliSecondLocator.__call__(self)
    432 st = _from_ordinal(dates.date2num(dmin))  # strip tz
    433 ed = _from_ordinal(dates.date2num(dmax))
--> 434 all_dates = date_range(start=st, end=ed, freq=freq, tz=tz).astype(object)
    436 try:
    437     if len(all_dates) > 0:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py:1172, in date_range(start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, name, closed, **kwargs)
   1169 if freq is None and com.any_none(periods, start, end):
   1170     freq = "D"
-> 1172 dtarr = DatetimeArray._generate_range(
   1173     start=start,
   1174     end=end,
   1175     periods=periods,
   1176     freq=freq,
   1177     tz=tz,
   1178     normalize=normalize,
   1179     closed=closed,
   1180     **kwargs,
   1181 )
   1182 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dtarr, tz=dtarr.tz, freq=dtarr.freq, name=name)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py:365, in DatetimeArray._generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, ambiguous, nonexistent, closed)
    362 freq = to_offset(freq)
    364 if start is not None:
--> 365     start = Timestamp(start)
    367 if end is not None:
    368     end = Timestamp(end)

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx:418, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx:320, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx:399, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_datetime_to_tsobject()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx:117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds()

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 53-06-20 13:53:27

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfBoundsDatetime                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py:43, in show(close, block)
     39 try:
     40     for figure_manager in Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
     41         display(
     42             figure_manager.canvas.figure,
---> 43             metadata=_fetch_figure_metadata(figure_manager.canvas.figure)
     44         )
     45 finally:
     46     show._to_draw = []

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py:231, in _fetch_figure_metadata(fig)
    228 # determine if a background is needed for legibility
    229 if _is_transparent(fig.get_facecolor()):
    230     # the background is transparent
--> 231     ticksLight = _is_light([label.get_color()
    232                             for axes in fig.axes
    233                             for axis in (axes.xaxis, axes.yaxis)
    234                             for label in axis.get_ticklabels()])
    235     if ticksLight.size and (ticksLight == ticksLight[0]).all():
    236         # there are one or more tick labels, all with the same lightness
    237         return {'needs_background': 'dark' if ticksLight[0] else 'light'}

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py:234, in <listcomp>(.0)
    228 # determine if a background is needed for legibility
    229 if _is_transparent(fig.get_facecolor()):
    230     # the background is transparent
    231     ticksLight = _is_light([label.get_color()
    232                             for axes in fig.axes
    233                             for axis in (axes.xaxis, axes.yaxis)
--> 234                             for label in axis.get_ticklabels()])
    235     if ticksLight.size and (ticksLight == ticksLight[0]).all():
    236         # there are one or more tick labels, all with the same lightness
    237         return {'needs_background': 'dark' if ticksLight[0] else 'light'}

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1249, in Axis.get_ticklabels(self, minor, which)
   1247 if minor:
   1248     return self.get_minorticklabels()
-> 1249 return self.get_majorticklabels()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1201, in Axis.get_majorticklabels(self)
   1199 def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1200     """Return this Axis' major tick labels, as a list of `~.text.Text`."""
-> 1201     ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1202     labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()]
   1203     labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()]

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1371, in Axis.get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1369 r"""Return the list of major `.Tick`\s."""
   1370 if numticks is None:
-> 1371     numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
   1373 while len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:
   1374     # Update the new tick label properties from the old.
   1375     tick = self._get_tick(major=True)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1277, in Axis.get_majorticklocs(self)
   1275 def get_majorticklocs(self):
   1276     """Return this Axis' major tick locations in data coordinates."""
-> 1277     return self.major.locator()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py:1343, in AutoDateLocator.__call__(self)
   1341 dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1342 locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
-> 1343 return locator()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py:434, in MilliSecondLocator.__call__(self)
    432 st = _from_ordinal(dates.date2num(dmin))  # strip tz
    433 ed = _from_ordinal(dates.date2num(dmax))
--> 434 all_dates = date_range(start=st, end=ed, freq=freq, tz=tz).astype(object)
    436 try:
    437     if len(all_dates) > 0:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py:1172, in date_range(start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, name, closed, **kwargs)
   1169 if freq is None and com.any_none(periods, start, end):
   1170     freq = "D"
-> 1172 dtarr = DatetimeArray._generate_range(
   1173     start=start,
   1174     end=end,
   1175     periods=periods,
   1176     freq=freq,
   1177     tz=tz,
   1178     normalize=normalize,
   1179     closed=closed,
   1180     **kwargs,
   1181 )
   1182 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dtarr, tz=dtarr.tz, freq=dtarr.freq, name=name)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py:365, in DatetimeArray._generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, ambiguous, nonexistent, closed)
    362 freq = to_offset(freq)
    364 if start is not None:
--> 365     start = Timestamp(start)
    367 if end is not None:
    368     end = Timestamp(end)

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx:418, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx:320, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx:399, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_datetime_to_tsobject()

File pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx:117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds()

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 53-06-20 13:53:27
```

Comment: I have no errors with a more recent config. The culprit seems to be `matplotlib` in your case.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Could you tell me the versions you're using ?
Just saw I didn't put the matplotlib version ;  matplotlib==3.5.2

Comment: I tested on python 3.8, pandas 1.4.1, matplotlib 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with pandas (or maybe a issue between pandas and matplotlib).
Upgrading to pandas 1.4.3 fixed the issue.

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: pandas 1.0.1 was quite an old one, definitely worth the update in any case ;)